# Automatically create card on another HTML page including form information

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm currently creating a website with a list of members on a page.
Members will register via a form, and once the form is filled in, I would like a card component to be created on another page (which will be password protected and only usable by an admin) with the choice to either accept the members request (of which their name will be automatically added to the members page) or decline the request, in which case the card will be deleted.

Can anyone suggest how I might go about automatically creating a card including information via the form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure to show us your effort, what have you tried and what is going wrong as well the expected outcome.

Comment: It simply another field in the database. `Approved`: true|false

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very general.
The easiest way is to use php to control the data of your form and with mysql PDO to insert them into a database.
Then in the database add a column for each registered "status", that when it is at 1, you post it as a confirmed member. If it is at 0 it must be confirmed.
I hope I've helped you